# Google Chrome console unstoppable Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, console

Seems like something wrong happened with my Google Chrome. I'm getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null             **VM34153:1**

that is counting up unstoppable, at **any** site I open, even Stackoverflow. Also it says that this error happens somewhere at `VM34153:1`. I tried disable any adblock addons. Nothing helps. Firefox console looks okay. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. I have good news for me and somebody who has the same trouble. The problem (as almost everything that gone wrong in Chrome) caused because of Google Chrome profile. I connected to Chrome from another user and the problem gone away. Now I need to reset crashed user in someway.